# The map does not reset the value of the key

Tags: scala

I wrote the function to count the the occurrence of each char in the string, for example, "aadb  a", it should return a->3, d->1, b->1, the map size should be 3, but now it is wrong

Below is the my code: may  I know the problem?

```
def checkPalindrome(str:String): Int={
   str.foldLeft(HashMap.empty[Char, Int]){(map, char)=> (char) match{
     case ' '=>map
     case _ =>  map+(char -> (map.getOrElse(char, 0) + 1))
   }
   }.size
 }
```

Comment: Your code works fine. I just had to add `import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap` at the top before I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the HashMap to Map and it is giving me correct results  as expected by you !

```
scala> 

scala> def checkPalindrome(str:String): Int={
     |    str.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int]){(map, char)=> (char) match{
     |      case ' '=>map
     |      case _ =>  map+(char -> (map.getOrElse(char, 0) + 1))
     |    }
     |    }.size
     |  }
checkPalindrome: (str: String)Int

scala> checkPalindrome("aadb a")
res6: Int = 3
```

Comment: Which one is it java.util.HashMap or scala.collection.mutable.HashMap ?

Answer (score 0):

```
"aadb a".toCharArray.filterNot(_ ==' ').groupBy(c=>c).map{case (c ,ca ) => c -> ca.length }
```

Comment: Hi, May I know what does the groupby(c=>c) mean? thanks

Comment: short for  (c: Char => c)  or { case c:Char => c} group by each char instance which gives you a char and array of each of its instances (which you can then map over and return the size)